# php POST stream_context_create and file_get_contents

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I have a script that previously worked, but apparently the website it downloads a file from has changed their format somehow.  I've altered the POST request content and header to what I think it should be, but it doesn't pull the file like I would expected.  Here's the script snippit I have now for that function:

```
$url='http://mansfield.tea.state.tx.us/TEA.AskTED.Web/Forms/DownloadFile.aspx?';
$header= "Host: mansfield.tea.state.tx.us\r\n";
$header.= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0\r\n";
$header.= "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
$header.= "Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5\r\n";
$header.= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n";
$header.= "Referer: http://mansfield.tea.state.tx.us/TEA.AskTED.Web/Forms/DownloadFile.aspx\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Length: 14067\r\n";
$header.= "Cookie: ga=GA1.3.400055834.1504257175; ASP.NET_SessionId=cj020m45uwj5hpmwaclhvmuk\r\n";
$header.= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
$header.= "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n";
$postdata= array(
    "__VIEWSTATE" => "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…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",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" => "44F2C40C",
    "btnDownloadFile" => "Download+File",
    "ddlSortOrder" => "School+Number"
);
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($postdata),
        'header'  => $header
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

It SHOULD return a file with a list of Texas schools and school data, but does not.

I took the information for the header ($header) section and content ($postdata) sections from a webdeveloper console.  The website it pulls the data from is http://mansfield.tea.state.tx.us/TEA.AskTED.Web/Forms/DownloadFile.aspx.

Any ideas on how I fix these headers and content to get the file to download via CLI in php?

Thanks

Comment: Please reduce your question to the smallest sample. Not all headers are required I support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewState changes everytime, so scrap the viewstate with [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and pass it

here is the working code

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="http://mansfield.tea.state.tx.us/TEA.AskTED.Web/Forms/DownloadFile.aspx";
$html=file_get_html($url);
$viewstate = $html->find('input',0)->value;


$url='http://mansfield.tea.state.tx.us/TEA.AskTED.Web/Forms/DownloadFile.aspx?';
$header= "Host: mansfield.tea.state.tx.us\r\n";
$header.= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0\r\n";
$header.= "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
$header.= "Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5\r\n";
$header.= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n";
$header.= "Referer: http://mansfield.tea.state.tx.us/TEA.AskTED.Web/Forms/DownloadFile.aspx\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Length: 14067\r\n";
$header.= "Cookie: ga=GA1.3.400055834.1504257175; ASP.NET_SessionId=cj020m45uwj5hpmwaclhvmuk\r\n";
$header.= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
$header.= "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n";
$postdata= array(
    "__VIEWSTATE" => $viewstate,
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" => "44F2C40C",
    "btnDownloadFile" => "Download+File",
    "ddlSortOrder" => "School+Number"
);
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($postdata),
        'header'  => $header
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $file;


?>
```

Comment: That's got it N B Sri Harsha.  A few minor changes to the code to ensure the content length is correct.

$header.="Content-Length: ".strlen($postdata)."\r\n"